# Does Hinduism have any significance of herbs like brahmi and ashwagandha?

Tags: ayurveda

Brahmi and ashwagandha are Ayurvedic herbs which are generally is used for increasing vitality, memory and immunity etc.

The effectiveness of these herbs was proven in various clinical studies.

I was wondering if there was any evidence in the Hinduism religion which supports the effectiveness of these herbs.

Comment: Hinduism and Ayurveda are not different. If its in Ayurveda then it is very much Hinduism religion. Please do not think that Ayurveda is different from Hinduism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes , the effectiveness of  herb    Brahmi ( Bacopa monnieri) and its   usage is mentioned in  [**Garuda Purana**](http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/garud-puran/garuda-vol-2/chapter-01/topic-88)  - Achara Kanda -Chapter 174 -  These ayurvedic herb helps in improving intellect and memory.

Garuda Purana is mentioning a Ghrtam (Herbal Ghee) called **Brahmi Gratham** . The Garuda Purana is also providing us the method of preparation and formula of this Ghrtam as talk between Lord Dhanvantari And Sushruta.

> धन्वतरिरुवाच । घृततैलादि वक्ष्यामि शृणु सुश्रुत रोगनुत् ।
>   शङ्खपुष्पी वचा सोमा **ब्राह्मी** ब्रह्मसुवर्चला ॥ 1.174.1 ॥
>  अभया च
>   गुडूची च अटरूपकवागुजी ।
>  एतैरक्षसमैर्भागैर्घृतप्रस्थं विपाचयेत् ॥
>   1.174.1  ॥
>
> Dhanvantari said-  Here me , O Susruta, who art well conversant with
>   the nature of diseases , dicource on preparations and efficacies of
>   different medicinal oils and Ghrtas . Cook a Prastha measure of
>   clarified butter with the aksa measure of each of the following drugs
>   Viz. Shankhpushpi , Vaca , Soma , **Brahmi** , Suvarchala , Abhaya ,
>   Guduci , Ataru-Saka and Vaguci, in combination with prastha measure of
>   expressed juice of kantakari and the same quantity of milk.
>
> ---
>
> कण्टकार्या रसप्रस्थक्षीरप्रस्थममन्वितम् ।
>  एतद्ब्राह्मीघृतं
>   नाम श्रुतिमेधाकरं परम् ॥ 1. 174.3॥
>  त्रिफलाचित्रकबलानिर्गुण्डी
>   निम्बवासकाः ।
>  पुनर्नवा गुडूची च बृहती च शतावरी ॥ 1.174.4 ॥
>
> **This Ghrtam is called Brahmi Ghrtam . It improves the intellect and memory .** Cook a Ghrtam with Triphala ,Citrakam , vala , Nirgundi ,
>   Nimba ,Vasaka , Punarnava ,Guduci , the two kinds of Vrati and
>   Shatavari , or with as many of them as are available.

---

A similar description can also be found in Ayurvedic Granthas like [**Sushruta Samhita**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sushruta-samhita-volume-4-cikitsasthana/d/doc142941.html) - **Chapter XXVIII - Elixirs (rasayana) to improve memory and life span**, where this medicinal herb Brahmi and its preparation called  Brahmi Ghrtam a kind of Rasayana and benefits  of both are mentioned.

> He should then take the expressed juice of the Brahmi in an adequate
>   dose after consecrating the juice a thousand times with the proper
>   Mantras. After the medicine had been fully digested he should be
>   advised to take in the evening Yavagu (gruel) without any salt; or
>   with boiled milk in the event of his being habituated to its use. **A
>   continuous use of the medicine for a week improves the memory, leads
>   to the expansion of the** **intellectual faculties and imparts a
>   celestical glow to the complexion.**

---

Ashwagandha and Brahmi are more like medicinal herbs . Unlike Durva ,Tulsi Etc. these herbs are not used in worship of deities , in puja , but mostly used for medicinal effect these have on our mind and body. 
In [**Rig-Veda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10097.htm) mandala 10 -Sukta 97 - **Oushadhi Sukta** . These medicinal herbs are said to  free us from our sin and all the medicinal herbs are  revered well.

> मुञ्चन्तु मा शपथ्यादथो वरुण्यादुत | 
>  अथो यमस्यपड्बीशात सर्वस्माद
>   देवकिल्बिषात | | RV 10.97.16 ||
>
> muñcantu mā śapathyādatho varuṇyāduta | 
>  atho yamasyapaḍbīśāt
>   sarvasmād devakilbiṣāt ||
>
> 16 Release me from the curse's plague and woe that comes from Varuṇa;
>   Free me from Yama's fetter, from sin and offence against the Gods.

Although Ashwagandha and Brahmi  are  effective for all the people , but they are more important to Dwija Brahmacharis i.e. Unmarried Students who is either doing Veda-Adhyayana or general studies. Since these hearbs  relieve stress, increase energy levels and improve concentration and memory , which are essential while student life.

---

---

[image]